# Displaying a tooltip when mouse hover is done in progressbar

Tags: javascript, angular7

I am trying to display a tooltip when user do a mouse over in my progressbar:
[image]

So the tool tip should be shown above the blue line or on the progress bar

Like this:
[image]

I'm following this website: [PrimeNg tooltip](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/tooltip)

I have done all the imports like:

```
import {TooltipModule} from 'primeng/tooltip';
```

My code look like this:

```
  <div>
      <table>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of freqValues | keyvalue: valueAscOrder">
                <td class="first">{{ item.value.name }}</td>
                <td class="middle">
                  <p-progressBar value={{item.value.pValue}} pTooltip="Enter your username" tooltipPosition="top"></p-progressBar>   // here is tooltip integration
                 </td>
                 <td class="last">{{item.value.value}}</td>
                 </tr>
                 </table>
                      </div>
```

Note: The above code output looks like the 1st image have tag Unique Values.
Can anyone suggest something how to do this?

Comment: What issue did you face? Do you get any errors? Also would be great if you can create a stackblitz demo..

Comment: no errors I'm getting it's simply not displaying the pTooltip attribute value when mouse is hover over the progressbar

Comment: works for me. Can you use this stckblitx to replicate your issue. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-st33st